# veracrypt: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: gtk, snap, 18.10, veracrypt

I'm unable to run Veracrypt on 18.10 Cosmic, it says that gtk library is missing.

```
veracrypt: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I `locate` it, it is there, as a snap package

```
$ locate libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.30
```

How to make it work with snap libgtk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the search on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=cosmic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0) you need to install one package:

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0
```

Your results from `locate` command are correct, but these libraries are used locally by their parent Snaps.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. It used to work out of the box on 18.04.